# How to take a user input and pass that to a predictive model

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, user-input

I have a dataframe on which I have built a predictive model. The data is divided to train and test, and I have used Randomforest classifier.

Now, The user pass a new data, which needs to pass through this model and give the result.

It is a text data, and below is the dataframe:

```
Description          Category
Rejoin this domain   Network
Laptop crashed       Hardware
Installation Error   Software
```

Code :

```
############### Feature extraction ##############
countvec = CountVectorizer()
counts = countvec.fit_transform(read_data['Description'])
df = pd.DataFrame(counts.toarray())
df.columns = countvec.get_feature_names()
print(df)

########## Join with original data ##############
df = read_data.join(df)
a = list(df.columns.values)

########## Creating the dependent variable class for "Category" variable ###########
factor = pd.factorize(df['Category'])
df.Category = factor[0]
definitions = factor[1]
print(df.Category.head())
print(definitions)

########## Creating the dependent variable class for "Description" variable ###########
factor = pd.factorize(df['Description'])
df.Description = factor[0]
definitions_1 = factor[1]
print(df.Description.head())
print(definitions_1)

######### Split into Train and Test data #######################
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.80, random_state = 21)

############# Random forest classification model #########################
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 42)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

######### Predicting the Test set results ##############
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

#####Reverse factorize (converting y_pred from 0s,1s and 2s to original class for "Category" ###############
reversefactor = dict(zip(range(3),definitions))
y_test = np.vectorize(reversefactor.get)(y_test)
y_pred = np.vectorize(reversefactor.get)(y_pred)

#####Reverse factorize (converting y_pred from 0s,1s and 2s to original class for "Description" ###############
reversefactor = dict(zip(range(53),definitions_1))
X_test = np.vectorize(reversefactor.get)(X_test)
```

Comment: what data user provides ? Do you want to append that data to your train data and then want to train the model on that new data ? And in which form your original data is present ...  I mean in some `csv` file or some other format ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do prediction on the user's data, then I would simply load the new csv (or other format) containing the user's data (making sure the columns are the same as in the original training dataset, minus the dependent variable obviously) and you can pull the predictions for your task:

```
user_df = pd.read_csv("user_data.csv")

#insert a preprocessing step if needed to make sure user_df is identical to the original dataset

new_predictions = classifier.predict(user_df)
```